# How to use complex header file in keil uvision 4?

Tags: file, header

Following is the program I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{   
unsigned char i,j,p,q;
complex arr[3][2]={{60 ,0},{80 ,-120},{100, -240}};
complex fabcr[3][1]={60+0i,-40-69.2820i,-50+86.6025i};
complex fa012[3][1], D[3][1],B[3][1],Vbal[3][1];
complex Vpol[3][2];
complex sum,l;
complex A[3][3]={{1  , 1 ,  1}, {1 ,-0.5+0.866i ,-0.5-0.866i}, {1 ,-0.5-0.866i, -0.5+0.866i}};
complex invA[3][3]=  {{0.3333 - 0.0000i ,  0.3333 + 0.0000i,   0.3333},          
                    {0.3333 ,-0.1667 - 0.2887i,  -0.1667 + 0.2887i},
                   { 0.3333 + 0.0000i , -0.1667 + 0.2887i , -0.1667 - 0.2887i}};
complex a=-0.5+0.866i;
//a^2 =-0.5-0.866i
printf("%f +i %f \n  %f %f",creal(a),cimag(a),cabs(a),(180/M_PI)*carg(a));
printf("\n line voltage fabcr \n\n");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{            
       for(j=0;j<1;j++)
            {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(fabcr[i][j]),cimag(fabcr[i][j]));
            }
       printf("\n"); 
}
printf("\n A matrix \n\n");

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{            
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(A[i][j]),cimag(A[i][j]));
            }
       printf("\n"); 
}
printf("\ninvA matrix\n\n");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{            
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(invA[i][j]),cimag(invA[i][j]));
            }
       printf("\n \n"); 
}

//matrix multiplication
for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
         sum=0;       
         for(q=0;q<3;q++)
         {
           l=fabcr[q][0]*A[p][q];
           sum=sum+l;

              }      
           printf("%f i %f \n", creal(sum),cimag(sum));   
          //fa012[p][1]=(1/3)*creal(sum)+i*(1/3)*cimag(sum); 
          fa012[p][0]=sum*0.33;

     }
    printf("\n symmetrical componenet fa012\n \n"); 
    for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(fa012[p][0]),cimag(fa012[p][0]));
    }

D[0][0]=-fa012[0][0];
D[1][0]=0;
D[2][0]=-fa012[2][0];
printf("\n matrix D \n \n");
 for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(D[p][0]),cimag(D[p][0]));
    }
printf("\n\nzero and negative sequence component in line voltage terms\n\n");
 for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
         sum=0;       
         for(q=0;q<3;q++)
         {
           l=D[q][0]*invA[p][q];
           sum=sum+l;

              }      
           printf("%f i %f \n", creal(sum),cimag(sum));   
          //fa012[p][1]=(1/3)*creal(sum)+i*(1/3)*cimag(sum); 
          B[p][0]=sum*3;

     }
printf("\n\nfinal balanced voltage \n\n")   ;  
for(p=0;p<3;p++)
    {
     Vbal[p][0]=fabcr[p][0]+B[p][0];
     printf("\n %f i %f \n %f %f \n", creal( Vbal[p][0]),cimag(Vbal[p][0]),cabs(Vbal[p][0]),(180/M_PI)*carg(Vbal[p][0])); 
      }

   printf("\n\n conversion to polar cordinates \n\n") ;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{            
    Vpol[i][0]= cabs(Vbal[i][0]);
    Vpol[i][1]= (180/M_PI)*carg(Vbal[i][1]);
    printf("%f  %f \n",Vpol[i][0],Vpol[i][1]  );    

}     

getch();
}
```

If I want to use this in keil it shows error.
Please suggest how to do complex manipulations?
I also copied complex.h and _mingw.h from devcpp include folder to keil/c51/inc folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do four things to make your program compile using Keil uVision:

1. Add the switch `--c99` to the compiler arguments. The reason is that `armcc` shipped 
   with Keil uVision 4 uses C90 mode for *.c files as can be seen when calling `armcc` in 
   a terminal without arguments:

   `--c90          Switch to C mode (default for .c files)`
2. Change all the occurences of `complex` in your code to `float complex` or 
   `double complex` as these are the names for complex data types in C99. Look also
   [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Complex-Number-Types), for example.
3. The definitions of complex numbers like `-0.5+0.866i` do not work. Change these 
    to `-0.5+0.866*I`.
4. Make your own definition of `PI` as it is not defined in `<math.h>` which is shipped
   with `armcc`. You can do this using e.g.

   `#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795`

After these steps the code will at least compile. However, there are a few more problems:

1. You are using `%f` to output a complex value instead of a float in the line

   `printf("%f  %f \n",Vpol[i][0],Vpol[i][1]  );`

   As `Vpol[i][0]` is the the magnitude of a complex number and `Vpol[i][1]` its 
   argument, you might as well output `cabs(Vpol[i][0])` and `creal(Vpol[i][1])`.

   Of course, it would be even better to change the definition to `float Vpol[3][2];`
   as you are only storing real values in this array.
2. The function `getch()` might not be part of `<stdio.h>`, i.e. you possibly have to
   provide your own implementation before linking.
3. (Not really a "problem"). The variable `arr` is never used.

Hope that helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

int main()
{   
    unsigned char i,j,p,q;
    float complex fabcr[3][1] = {60+0*I,-40-69.2820*I,-50+86.6025*I};
    float complex fa012[3][1], D[3][1],B[3][1],Vbal[3][1];
    float Vpol[3][2];
    float complex sum,l;
    float complex A[3][3] = {{1, 1,            1}, 
                             {1, -0.5+0.866*I, -0.5-0.866*I}, 
                             {1, -0.5-0.866*I, -0.5+0.866*I}};
    float complex invA[3][3] 
        = {{0.3333 - 0.0000*I, 0.3333 + 0.0000*I,  0.3333},          
           {0.3333,            -0.1667 - 0.2887*I, -0.1667 + 0.2887*I},
           {0.3333 + 0.0000*I, -0.1667 + 0.2887*I, -0.1667 - 0.2887*I}};
    float complex a = -0.5+0.866*I;
    //a^2 =-0.5-0.866i
    printf("%f +i %f \n  %f %f", creal(a), cimag(a), 
                                 cabs(a), (180/M_PI) * carg(a));
    printf("\n line voltage fabcr \n\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {            
        for(j=0; j<1; j++)
        {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(fabcr[i][j]),cimag(fabcr[i][j]));
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("\n A matrix \n\n");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {            
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(A[i][j]),cimag(A[i][j]));
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("\ninvA matrix\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {            
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf( "%f +i %f ",creal(invA[i][j]),cimag(invA[i][j]));
        }
        printf("\n \n"); 
    }

    // matrix multiplication
    for(p=0; p<3; p++)
    {
        sum=0;       
        for(q=0; q<3; q++)
        {
            l=fabcr[q][0]*A[p][q];
            sum=sum+l;
        }      
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(sum),cimag(sum));   
        // fa012[p][1]=(1/3)*creal(sum)+i*(1/3)*cimag(sum); 
        fa012[p][0]=sum*0.33;
    }
    printf("\n symmetrical component fa012\n \n"); 
    for(p=0; p<3; p++)
    {
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(fa012[p][0]),cimag(fa012[p][0]));
    }

    D[0][0] = -fa012[0][0];
    D[1][0] = 0;
    D[2][0] = -fa012[2][0];
    printf("\n matrix D \n \n");
    for(p=0; p<3; p++)
    {
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(D[p][0]),cimag(D[p][0]));
    }
    printf("\n\nzero and negative sequence component in line voltage terms\n\n");
    for(p=0; p<3; p++)
    {
        sum=0;       
        for(q=0; q<3; q++)
        {
            l=D[q][0]*invA[p][q];
            sum=sum+l;
        }      
        printf("%f i %f \n", creal(sum),cimag(sum));   
        //fa012[p][1]=(1/3)*creal(sum)+i*(1/3)*cimag(sum); 
        B[p][0]=sum*3;
    }
    printf("\n\nfinal balanced voltage \n\n")   ;  
    for(p=0; p<3; p++)
    {
        Vbal[p][0] = fabcr[p][0]+B[p][0];
        printf("\n %f i %f \n %f %f \n", 
               creal(Vbal[p][0]), cimag(Vbal[p][0]),
               cabs(Vbal[p][0]), (180/M_PI) * carg(Vbal[p][0])); 
    }

    printf("\n\n conversion to polar cordinates \n\n") ;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {            
        Vpol[i][0] = cabs(Vbal[i][0]);
        Vpol[i][1] = (180/M_PI) * carg(Vbal[i][1]);
        printf("%f  %f \n", Vpol[i][0], Vpol[i][1]);    
    }     
}
```